# LilyPond does not create MIDI file

Tags: lilypond

I am a new user here. I have just installed LilyPond on Windows and I am having trouble creating MIDI files together with my scores. I am employing Frescobaldi as an editor, but the problem persists if I compile directly by drag-and-drop on the LilyPond icon.

Minimal (not) working example:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {{c' e' d'}}
\layout { }
\midi { }
```

Compling this bad boy here indeed produces the pdf with the score, but there is no sign of a MIDI output...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The same happens if I select "Create PDF" from the right-click menu. The log file is the following

## -*-compilation-*-

```
Processing C:/Users/carlo/Desktop/LilyPond files/Toy example/Toy-example.ly
Parsing...
Interpreting music...
Preprocessing graphical objects...
Finding the ideal number of pages...
Fitting music on 1 page...
Drawing systems...
Layout output to `/Users/carlo/Desktop/LilyPond files/Toy example/Toy-example.ps'...
Converting to `/Users/carlo/Desktop/LilyPond files/Toy example/Toy-example.pdf'...
Success: compilation successfully completed
```

However, compiling via command prompt does not work, i.e. the command "lilypond MyFile.ly" is not recognized as legit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `\midi` block is *inside* your `\score` block. (Otherwise LilyPond doesn't know what you want to midi-fy.)

Your line of `score {{c' e' d'}}` ends the `\score` block; deleting the final `}` and moving it to the end of that line of code should solve the problem:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  {
    c' e' d'
  }
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

Lastly, note that you can specify the tempo for the midi output if you like. `\midi { \tempo 4=100 }`, for instance, specifies a tempo of quarter note = 100.